# Securing the session cookie in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

My problem is my session cookies aren't being marked as secure. They are successfully being marked as HTTPonly but not secure.

The code I have tried as bellow:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true">
```

What should be done to mark the cookie secure?

Comment: How about you start by telling us what kind of system/language this is supposed to be? And please add appropriate tags to the question as well.

Comment: In what language you are trying to achieve this ?

Comment: This is for a system which is being developed in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below code in Asp.net Application

```
if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
    {
        if (s == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName || s.ToLower() == "asp.net_sessionid")
        {
             Response.Cookies[s].Secure = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also add the below code :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms ...  requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I have tried this as well. But still It did not show as secure.

Comment: Is you site is SSL secured ?? SSL is must in order to achieve your requirement